# file saving(object) to android

Tags: android, input

below are 4 functions i found(after intense googling) 
(my objective is to be able to write instances of objects i created and then retrieve them later)

```
public static Object deserializeObject(byte[] bytes)
{
    // TODO: later read Region object saved in file named by the time stamp during
    // saving.
    // ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new
    // FileInputStream(fileName));

    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        Object object = in.readObject();
        in.close();

        return object;
      } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        Log.e("deserializeObject", "class not found error", cnfe);

        return null;
      } catch(IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("deserializeObject", "io error", ioe);

        return null;
      }
}


/**
 * Writes content to internal storage making the content private to 
 * the application. The method can be easily changed to take the MODE 
 * as argument and let the caller dictate the visibility: 
 * MODE_PRIVATE, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, etc.
 * 
 * @param filename - the name of the file to create
 * @param content - the content to write
 */
public void writeInternalStoragePrivate(
        String filename, byte[] content) {
    try {
        //MODE_PRIVATE creates/replaces a file and makes 
        //  it private to your application. Other modes:
        //    MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE
        //    MODE_WORLD_READABLE
        //    MODE_APPEND
        FileOutputStream fos = 
           openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(content);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



/**
 * Reads a file from internal storage
 * @param filename the file to read from
 * @return the file content
 */
public byte[] readInternalStoragePrivate(String filename) {
    int len = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nrb = fis.read(buffer, 0, len); // read up to len bytes
        while (nrb != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, nrb);
            nrb = fis.read(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        buffer = baos.toByteArray();
        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

and i am using this to try to read the object 
q1.a=12;

```
      byte []q=serializeObject(q1); 
      writeInternalStoragePrivate("shared",q);


byte []w=readInternalStoragePrivate("shared"); 
      fl y=(fl) deserializeObject(w);
```

(the first 2 line are serialisation and writing, and the other two are reading and deserialisation.)

but, every time i switch off the app, the data gets lost,and its reset to 0.

(i am a middle school guy, so , i know very less, please try to be sparing )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `Write` and `read` you need to Wrap FileOutput/InputStream to a ObjectOutput/InputStream, you are calling `readObject()` on top of the code but you never call `writeObject()` so the `Serialization process` was never done at first.

EDIT 3: i decided to erase all the trying code to make you realize how to do this and put some copy/paste working code, still you need to learn from this code (is not using convetions or good practice, that's homework for you):

1- Create a new clean project.

2- add this to your MainActivity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.w("asd","saasd");

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void save(View view){
    writer.execute();
}

public void read(View view){
    reader.execute();
}

private  AsyncTask writer = new AsyncTask(){

  @Override
  protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
      writeConfigurationFile(new MyNumber(5));
      return null;
  }
};

private AsyncTask reader = new AsyncTask(){
    MyNumber number;
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
       number = readConfigurationFile();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object object) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number_info);
                t.setText(String.valueOf(number.getA()));
            }
        });

    }
};


private void writeConfigurationFile(MyNumber number) {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput("MyNumberFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(number);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("LOG:", e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("LOG:", e.getMessage());

    }
}

private MyNumber readConfigurationFile() {
    FileInputStream fis;
   MyNumber number = null;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput("MyNumberFile");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        number = (MyNumber) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("LOG:", e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("LOG:", e.getMessage());

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("LOG:", e.getMessage());

    }
    return number;
}

}
```

3- create a new class called MyNumber in the same package where MainActivity is and add this to the MyNumber.java file:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
* Created by joseph on 09/08/13.
*/
public class MyNumber implements Serializable {
int a;

public MyNumber(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}
}
```

and last the activity_main.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="save"/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Read"
        android:id="@+id/read"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:onClick="read"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Number From File"
        android:id="@+id/number_info"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

add this to your AndroidManifest.xml above the `Application` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then run the program, when you click `save button` a new MyNumber object with an int of value 5 is created and Serialized, when you click `read button` we read the file and set the number of the int in the textView after this you could close the app and open it again and click read and the number saved in the file will show up (since the file still attached to the app data), if you don't understand or don't achieve what you want with this code I'm really sorry about it since this is not a web page where your homework will be done, don't expect this ever again, I'm just trying to help you but with code like this I'm not helping you to learn at all.

Comment: this is it to the whole code? 
i dont know what to modify, please tell me a bit more about it.

Comment: @user2666729 i edit my post, you should achieve it now, if not, I recommend you to read a tutorial of "basic serialization".

Comment: in deserializeObject, its returning an error 
cannot make static reference to the non-static method. 

also, how will i deserialize a byte array with what you told me to do ? 
(there is no parameter in deserializeObject anymore)

Comment: @user2666729 try the Edit2.

Comment: this is returning many errors. 
suppose i have an object fl, with int a as a data menber. 
how should i write it?

Comment: its showing errors
[2013-08-10 14:09:40 - fresg] W/ResourceType( 2584): Bad XML block: header size 105 or total size 6881476 is larger than data size 0
and mrore

Comment: i am following this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzwiuRDgSSY 
but, i cant seem to be able to create the file filename. 
i tried in both, java application and android mode . 

please tell me with reference to that .

Comment: im sorry  @user2666729 the code i  made specifically for you above works and it shows in the easiest possible way how to `Write/Read` a file in `Internal Storage` in Android, if you can't even `copy/paste` i can't really help you then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a project and we ended up using an SQLite database. If you want persistence, there is not really an alternative right now (DB4O etc. all do not work)...

Check out http://sqlite.com/ there are many many tutorials out there for SQLite!

You really have to restructure your code for a database solution (retrieve and insert objects) but sadly, there is no real alternative (do not use a dirty way such as storing a csv-file or similar approaches...)

Edit: Okay if you just want to store 5 variables you can use The SharedPreferences.

Comment: when the issue is about saving like 5-10 variables as `Configuration` I don't really see the need to use SQLite, and writing a file via Serialization is more easy than SQLite, one should use the best that fit (in terms of a good implementation-performance-cleaner way) the needs IMHO.

Comment: Okay I edited that. For 5-10 variables, use I would recommend SharedPreferences.

Comment: yup, and again SharedPreferences only store primitives, so serialization still the way if you want to keep the structure of the Object itself instead of key-value pairs.

Comment: i am following this(i tried this both, on android AND as a simple java application) 
but my "data.bin" file is not getting created. 

tell me where i am wrong?